# PHP strings - if part of needle is found in haystack

Tags: php, string, compare, explode

I've tried searching for a solution online but have had no luck (i´m a PHP beginner). I have two `strings` (collection of phone numbers with a time-stamps) that have `comma separated values`. I need to check if a specific part of text between the commas from `sting A` can be found in `string B`.

Here is an example of sting A:

```
9858264-2012-12-05T00:11:28.806Z,1265482-2012-12-05T22:19:49.769Z,9598643-2012-12-05T22:46:17.115Z,
```

Here is an example og sting B:

```
5555649-2012-12-05T22:37:23.765Z,3594595-2012-12-05T22:44:36.363Z,8549851-2012-12-05T22:46:01.259Z,9598643-2012-12-05T22:46:09.600Z
```

In the above strings, the below two values are very similar (only few seconds in the time-stamp are different):

```
From string A: 9598643-2012-12-05T22:46:17.115Z
From string B: 9598643-2012-12-05T22:46:09.600Z
```

What I need to do is `COUNT` the number of values between commas in `string A` that match in `string B` **apart from the last 5 characters in the time-stamp** as those could be the same occurrences but with +/- a few seconds apart.

I have thought of using php `explode` to get every value into an array and then comparing them, but I´m rather lost at this point when it comes to array and also on how to compare one array value to the other minus the last 5 characters of an value.

Comment: `substr($s, 0, -5)` to get the string minus 5 chars.

Comment: Are these lists sorted?  It would make your challenge easier if they are.

Comment: does stringA and stringB always contain the same number of values between commas?

Comment: @`Jack` - Thanks. That will help further along the way.
@ `psyklopz` - At the moment they are random. These are missed (sting A) vs received (sting B) call logs in a call center.
@ `kennypu` - Sadly no. String A could contain any number of values but always fewer values than String B (as received calls are always equal to greater than missed calls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
function make_string_into_nice_array ($string) {
    $string_array = explode(',',$string);
    return array_map(function($str) {
        return substr($str, 0, -5);    
    }, $string_array);
}

$array_a = make_string_into_nice_array($string_a);
$array_b = make_string_into_nice_array($string_b);

$matched_array = array_intersect($array_a, $array_b);

echo count($matched_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$arrayA = explode(',', $StringA); // Parse the string into array elements, using comma as delimiter.
$arrayB = explode(',', $StringB);

$matches = array(); // Declare the array that will be the output.
foreach ($arrayA as $aValue) { // Iterate through each element of A.
    foreach ($arrayB as $bValue) { // Iterate through each element of B.
        // Take the value of element A (chopping off the last 5 characters) and compare with the value of element B (chopping off the last 5 characters)
        if (substr($aValue, 0, strlen($aValue)-5) == substr($bValue, 0, strlen($bValue)-5))) {
            // If there's a match, iterate the count of that particular key in your output array.
            $matches[substr($aValue, 0, strlen($aValue)-5)] += 1;
        }
    }
}
echo count($matches); // Print the number of keys that are duped.
print_r($matches); // Look at each individual key and the number of duplicated instances.
```

Comment: Thanks. I´ll check this solution out.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I think it's more useful to combine the two strings, parse them, then look for phone numbers with more than one call.

```
<?php
$input =
   trim(
      '9858264-2012-12-05T00:11:28.806Z,1265482-2012-12-05T22:19:49.769Z,9598643-2012-12-05T22:46:17.115Z,' .
      '5555649-2012-12-05T22:37:23.765Z,3594595-2012-12-05T22:44:36.363Z,8549851-2012-12-05T22:46:01.259Z,9598643-2012-12-05T22:46:09.600Z',
      ','
   ); //gets rid of leading/trailing commas
$raw_arr = explode(',', $input);

$phone_records = array();

foreach( $raw_arr as $entry ) {
   $temp = explode('T', $entry);
   $time = $temp[1];
   $temp = explode('-', $temp[0]);
   $phone = array_shift($temp);
   $date = implode('-', $temp);

   if( ! isset($phone_records[$phone]) ) {
      $phone_records[$phone] = array();
   }
   $phone_records[$phone][] = array($date, $time);
}

//print_r($phone_records);

foreach( $phone_records as $number => $entries ) {
   if( count($entries) > 1 ) {
      printf('%s: %s', $number, var_export($entries, TRUE));
   }
}
```

Output:

```
9598643: array (
  0 =>
  array (
    0 => '2012-12-05',
    1 => '22:46:17.115Z',
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    0 => '2012-12-05',
    1 => '22:46:09.600Z',
  ),
)
```

You could also use this code to parse each input into its own array, then run through one with a foreach loop and check if the values are `array_key_exists($arr1_key, $arr2)`.